# Webpack Encore didn't write css and js in folder "build" in production environment of Symfony 4

Tags: azure, symfony, deployment, webpack-encore

I'm working with Symfony 4 and my deployment platform is Microsoft Azure. This is my website :https://synergie-2i.azurewebsites.net/SynergieInformatique/public/index.php/.
My problem is when my environment is in production, my css and js aren't loaded. When inspect my page in services i see my folder SynergieInformatique/public and an other folder name build. Inside there is 3 css files but there is nothing inside. I think webpack didn't write my css in these files.

I have try to copy my css and put in the empty css file and it works but i don't know how make this with symfony.
When i'm in dev environement, the folder build is in SynergieInformatique/public and my css is loaded.

```
###webpack.config.js : ###
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
   .addEntry('owlcarouselcss','./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css')
    .addEntry('owlcarouseljs','./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    });
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();`
```

What are the step for deploy an symfony 4 application with Webpack and how i can have my css and js load on production environement ? 
If you need more informations ask me :)

Comment: It's more related to Azure than production env., if you put your application in dev mode in Azure build doesn't work anyway, I'm wrong ?

Comment: it's works if my application is in dev mode

Answer (score 0):

I have found, my links were bad. I use `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}` and this doesn't search at the good folder so i remplace this by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/SynergieInformatique/public//build/app.css">` and it works.